# Discover which Chrome flags are supported in Electron

Tags: electron

I would like to find out which Chrome flags I can use in my version of Electron. In Chrome I can just go to `chrome://flags` or `about:flags` and see a list. That does not work in Electron - it gives this error:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://flags/
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: I found [an issue about displaying the currently *enabled* flags at least](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/22465).

Comment: Ah and here is [this specific issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/22209).